# dynamic factory in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a situation where I have 8 objects that all inherit from one object. For certain purposes, these objects **must** be their own classes, but at the **initial creation** there is nothing different about them.

They cannot be created as the base object, they must be added to the database as their own object. This is not negotiable.

It seems stupid to create 16 controller actions and 8 views for this. I only have to know which type is being added, never anything different. So basically I need to do the following ...

```
abstract class Base {
  Guid Id { get; set; }
  string Name { get; set; }
  string Description { get; set; }
}

class Alpha : Base { // }
class Beta : Base { // }
class Sigma : Base { // }
class Delta : Base { // }

class ObjectViewModel {
  string Name { get; set; }
  string Description { get; set; }
}


ActionResult Create(){
 return View();
}

[HttpPost]
ActionResult Create(ObjectViewModel model) {
   // determine which type needs to be created
   Factory.Create(model); // the factory will create the right object based on the type
   repository.Add(factoryCreatedObject);
   // ... 
}
```

It seems simple enough, but it just is not working. I've tried putting a `System.Type` property on the ViewModel - it just doesn't work. The only thing I have been able to get to work is to use a gigantic `switch` statement, but that seems like a poor approach.

Is there any way I can get this done without excessive redundancy?

Comment: It sounds like you need to use reflection, but before I answer, can you elaborate on what exactly is not working? It sounds like you do have one controller, but the factoryCreatedObject is not being added to the repository? Or it's the wrong type? Also, are your objects implementing an Interface, or are they derived from an abstract class?

Comment: They are derived from an abstract class. The problem is that there is no way for the Controller to know what type of object to create, since it always gets an instance of the base class back.

Comment: Is there anything else in the Request object that would allow your code to know the specific type of object? If so, you could do a custom model binder for that Action.

Comment: I would not have any idea how to even start something like that.

Comment: No, there is no other unique data. All of the unique data has to come later on in the process. This stage only creates the initial object by type.

Comment: Then how is your big switch statement working?

Comment: It isn't. That's the problem. It only works if I hard-code in the possibilities. So if a new class is added in the future, it has to be updated in about 5 different places.

Comment: I don't see a way around this. If there is nothing distinguishable at the time of the call to your Action, then you can't cast it as a more specific type. You need to add some information to the incoming Post or do it manually.

Comment: If I add more information, is there anything I can do other than a switch statement and 8+ different constructor calls?

Comment: Well there is a possibility that you can use generics, but there's no way for me to know without more information. The other possibility that the big switch statement could be centralized and thus easier to maintain. Again, more info would be needed.

Comment: How could I use generics? I can change the ObjectViewModel however needed, but that wouldn't help much. Even if I have the class type, I can't do anything with it. I cannot create an instance of an object from a generic type. And I have updated the post with more - that is literally everything pertinent to the classes at hand. Any other data in the sub-classes has absolutely nothing to do with this and is not in any way possible to be accessed ,used, set, or retrieved at this stage in the object creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about creating a custom model binder:

```
public class BaseModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    private Type _type;

    protected override ICustomTypeDescriptor GetTypeDescriptor(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetProvider(_type).GetTypeDescriptor(_type);
    }

    protected override object CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType)
    {
        var result = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("type");
        if (result == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("please provide a valid type parameter");
        }

        _type = Type.GetType(result.AttemptedValue);
        if (_type == null || !typeof(Base).IsAssignableFrom(_type))
        {
            throw new Exception("please provide a valid type parameter");
        }
        return Activator.CreateInstance(_type);
    }
}
```

which you would register in `Application_Start`:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(Base), new BaseModelBinder());
```

and now you could have the following controller action:

```
public ActionResult Foo(Base model)
{
    ... 
}
```

Now when you are invoking this action simply pass an additional `type` parameter indicating the concrete instance you would like to create. For example:

```
http://localhost:1203/?type=MvcApplication1.Models.Alpha&Id=21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D&Name=Test&Description=Somedescription&AlphaProp=alpha
```

Comment: I _think_ I get what you are saying, but how would that work with JSON model binding? If I put a list of types as a drop down list, it turns into a simple list of strings on the `POST`.

Comment: @Ciel, this wouldn't work with JSON request binding. You will need to tweak the `JsonValueProviderFactory` for this. As far as normal `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` POST requests are concerned you could have a simple form containing a dropdownlist with the different types and values as input fields. It will work the same as the GET request I've showed as far as you provide the same values in the form as I did in the query string.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this out when I can think more clearly here in a bit. I'm terrible with Reflection and I've never done a custom model binder before, but this seems like it touches on what I need to do.

Comment: Your answer did not solve the exact problem I have, but it did show me how to do a model binder in such a way that I have discovered a valid workaround. Here is what I did (this may take a few posts). -- First, I designed an `Attribute` named `EnumClassBinder` that takes a generic `T` as a constructor parameter. So I would decorate an enum value like this - `[EnumClassBinder(typeof(Namespace.Beta))] Beta`.

Comment: After that, I included the `Enum` in my `ViewModel`, and used code similar to what you posted to extract the enum field and reflect it, and get the `EnumClassBinder` attribute from it, and summon up the reflected class.